# Angular cannot assign var because is not a variable

Tags: angular, rest, api

I have a variable like this:

```
export var navigation = [
];
```

Import variable for use:

```
import { navigation } from 'app/navigation/navigation';
```

But when I want to use this variable a have the next error:

[image]

Comment: export let navigation

Comment: Nothing, it's the same error. :/    @Sachila Ranawaka

Comment: `this.navigation` is releated to your `export var navigation`. the statement `something = somethingElse` it'll return this error because you are not defining a var with that name. You could do `let something = somethingElse` and will work

Comment: Nothing :/ @ Jacopo Sciampi

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign data to exported values. They are read-only. When you `import { navigation } from 'app/navigation/navigation';` you cannot assign any value to navigation. You can only use it to display/use some data. If you want to assign value to the `navigator` use other approach, eg. use service.

Answer (score 1):

```
var navigation = [];
export default navigation;
```

and then :

```
import navigation from 'app/navigation/navigation';
```

Comment: I cannot import the variable. Error: It has no exported member 'navigation'. @selem mn

Comment: Where did you export it ? could you provide a simple [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com) for that please ?